How to animate header and profile image size based on scroll offset in Jetpack Compose?
I am creating a profile screen where I have added a TopBarBackground. I want the size of the TopBarBackground to decrease as the user scrolls the content. During this size reduction, the first content item should remain visible. Similarly, when scrolling back up, the first item should load correctly. If the user scrolls further, the resizing should work as expected. However, with my current code, when the user scrolls, the first content item becomes invisible while the size is decreasing.
TopBarBackground
@Composable
fun TopBarBackground(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    bottomRounded: Int = 60,
) {

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .drawBehind {
                val path = Path().apply {
                    moveTo(0f, 0f)
                    lineTo(0f, size.height)
                    quadraticTo(
                        size.width / 2, size.height + bottomRounded.dp.toPx(),
                        size.width, size.height
                    )
                    lineTo(size.width, 0f)
                    close()
                }

                val brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        LinearGradient1,
                        LinearGradient2
                    ),
                )
                drawPath(path, brush)
            }
    ) {

        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_topbar_background),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                    .padding(bottom = 20.sdp)
                    .fillMaxHeight(),
            )


        }


    }
}

Profile Screen
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()



    val totalScrollOffset by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            listState.firstVisibleItemIndex * 100 + listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        }
    }
    val animatedHeaderHeight by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = (150 - totalScrollOffset / 2).coerceIn(70, 150).sdp,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
    )

 val animateProfileImage by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = (80 - (totalScrollOffset / 2).coerceIn(0, 20)).sdp,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
    )
    val animateUserName by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = (16 - (totalScrollOffset / 2).coerceIn(0, 6)).sdp,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
    )


Surface {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = Color.White),
        ) {

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Box {
                    TopBarBackground(
                        modifier = Modifier.height(animatedHeaderHeight),

                        )

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 16.sdp)
                            .padding(horizontal = 10.sdp)
                    ) {

                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                            text = "Profile",
                            color = Color.White,
                            fontFamily = Inter600,
                            fontSize = 16.ssp
                        )

                    }
                }
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        .offset(y = -20.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.sdp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {

                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_profile),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                            .size(animateProfileImage)
                            .shadow(elevation = 10.sdp, shape = CircleShape)
                            .background(color = Color.White, shape = CircleShape)
                            .padding(10.sdp),
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(ThemeDarkGreen)

                    )

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                        text = userName,
                        color = Color.Black,
                        fontFamily = Inter600,
                        fontSize = animateUserName.value.toInt().ssp
                    )
                }
            }

            LazyColumn(
                state = listState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),

            ) {


                items(
                    items = settingsList,
                    key = { item -> item.text }) { item ->
                    SettingsOption(
                        iconId = item.iconId,
                        text = item.text,
                        onClick = item.action
                    )
                }
            }
}
}

With my current code, when the user scrolls, the first content item becomes invisible while the size is decreasing. Additionally, the scrolling is jittery and does not work properly, especially when the list of data is small.
